# Form validation, the function i call is not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

I'm creating a webpage and i have this form for creating a report , it has a subject input, email input, a select list and a text area. i'm trying to validate the form using Javascript and a function, the content of the function is not being read, and the form gets submitted when i click the submit button

this is my form code in html:

```js
function formValidations() {
  alert("why you little!")
  var valid = true;
  var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var problem = document.getElementByName("techtype")[0].value;
  var description = document.getElementById("description").value
  errors = document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "";
  errors2 = document.getElementById("errorMsg2").innerHTML = "";
  errors3 = document.getElementById("errorMsg3").innerHTML = "";
  errors4 = document.getElementById("errorMsg4").innerHTML = "";



  if (subject == "" || email == "" || description == "") {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "*Please fill out all of the required fields";
    valid = false;
  } else if (!isEmail(email)) {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg2").innerHTML = "*Please enter a valid email.";
    valid = false;
  } else if (description.length < 100) {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg3").innerHTML = "*Please be more specifict, use 100 characters minimum.";
    valid = false;
  } else if (problem.value == problemtype) {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg4").innerHTML = "*Please select a problem type.";
    valid = false;
  } else {
    alert("your report has been submitted successfully, thank you kindly!");

  }
  return valid;
}

function isEmail(email) {
  return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
```

```html
<div class="form1">
  <form method="GET" onsubmit=" return formValidations() " action="log-it-reports.html"><br>
    <div id="errorMsg"></div>
    <div>
      <label for="subject"><b>Subject:</label>
      <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject Title">
    </div>
    <div class="error" id="errorMsg2"></div>
    <div>
      <label for="email"><b>Email:</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="staff@wearview.com">
    </div>
    <div class="error" id="errorMsg3"></div>
    <div>
      <select name="techtype" id="problemtypes">
        <option value="problemtype">Problem Type</option>
        <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
        <option value="Software">Software</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="error" id="errorMsg4"></div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="description" name="descript" rows="15" cols="50">Issue Description here please..
            </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="error" id="errorMsg5"></div> <br>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is on the line where you define `problem`. Hit F12 to see the error message in the console. The type error breaks the code, and nothing is ever returned, that's why the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you so much Teemu, i removed that specific line where var "problem" is declared, and the rest of the validation started working, i will investigate further the error to know more,, you saved my time , i spent 2 hours already , God bless you man.

Comment: There should be `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementByName`.

Comment: How clumsy of me, that small s ..now everything is working just perfect, the entire form, thank you Teemu Superemu ^_^